# beautifulsoup select method returns traceback

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

well im still learning beautifulsoup module and im replcating this from the book automate the boring stuff with python i tried replcating the get amazon price script but i get a traceback on the .select() method 
the error 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'
 its getiing devastated with this error as i couldnt find much about it

```py
import bs4
import requests


header = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"}

def site(url):

    x = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    x.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x.text, "html.parser")
    p = soup.Select('#buyNewSection > a > h5 > div > div.a-column.a-span8.a-text-right.a-span-last > div > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.offer-price.a-text-normal')
    abc = p[0].text.strip()
    return abc

price = site('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994')
print('price is' + str(price))
```

it must return a list value containing the price but im stuck with this error

Comment: It means that element you are selecting no longer exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `soup.select` as opposed to `soup.Select`, your code does work, it just returns an empty list.The reason can see if we inspect the function you are using:

```
help(soup.Select)

Out[1]:
Help on NoneType object:

class NoneType(object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __bool__(self, /)
 |      self != 0
 |  
 |  __repr__(self, /)
 |      Return repr(self).
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Static methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
 |      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
```

Compared to:

```
help(soup.select)

Out[2]:
Help on method select in module bs4.element:

select(selector, namespaces=None, limit=None, **kwargs) method of bs4.BeautifulSoup instance
    Perform a CSS selection operation on the current element.

    This uses the SoupSieve library.

    :param selector: A string containing a CSS selector.

    :param namespaces: A dictionary mapping namespace prefixes
    used in the CSS selector to namespace URIs. By default,
    Beautiful Soup will use the prefixes it encountered while
    parsing the document.

    :param limit: After finding this number of results, stop looking.

    :param kwargs: Any extra arguments you'd like to pass in to
    soupsieve.select().
```

Having that said, it seems that the page structure is actually different than the one you are trying to get, missing the `<a>` tag.

```html
<div id="buyNewSection" class="rbbHeader dp-accordion-row">
   <h5>
      <div class="a-row">
         <div class="a-column a-span4 a-text-left a-nowrap">
            <span class="a-text-bold">Buy New</span>
         </div>
         <div class="a-column a-span8 a-text-right a-span-last">
            <div class="inlineBlock-display">
               <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
               <span class="a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal">$16.83</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </h5>
</div>
```

So this should work:

```py
p = soup.select('#buyNewSection > h5 > div > div.a-column.a-span8.a-text-right.a-span-last > div.inlineBlock-display > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.offer-price.a-text-normal')
abc = p[0].text.strip()
abc

Out[2]:
'$16.83'
```

Additionally, you could consider using a more granular approach that let's you debug your code better. For instance:

```py
buySection = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'buyNewSection'})
buySpan = buySection.find('span', attrs={'class': 'a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal'})

print (buyScan)
Out[1]:
'$16.83'
```